# getting error when call function of common helper in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, continuous-integration

I'm  facing a problem. it seems an error. error is:

> Non-static method common::get_nav_links() should not be called
>   statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

My code in view page is:

```
<?php $nav = common::get_nav_links();?>
```

Code in common helper is :

```
public static function get_nav_links() {
$CI = & get_instance();
$sql = "select * from news_category where parent_id=0 and position=1 order by sort asc";
$query = $CI->db->query($sql);
return $query->result_array();
```

}

how can i solve it

Comment: The problem is that you not call `$obj->get_nav_links()`, if php5.6+ you can do `$nav=(new common())->get_nav_links();` , but try first `$nav = $this->get_nav_links();` or `$nav = $this->common->get_nav_links();`

Comment: Thanks. it works nicely. $nav=(new common())->get_nav_links(); it's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you go to **application>config>autoload.php**

add your helper name in autoload.php page ($autoload['helper'] = array('common');)

then call your function on view page or any page:

get_nav_links();